# confused about this javascript behavior in closures

Tags: javascript

Geting a bit more into Javascript and OO programming but I'm not understanding this behavior here of what why my ojbect (myUser cannot access the property this.first_name as 'jon' and is instead undefined (hilighted in red in screen shot at bottom). Here's the code fragment in question:

```
function User(first_name, last_name){
    this.first_name=first_name;
    this.last_name=last_name;
}

// left in for completeness
User.prototype = {
    constructor: User,
    sayName: function(){
        console.log("My Name: " + this.first_name + " and " + this.last_name);
    }

}

User.prototype.whoWhat = function(){
    console.log(this.first_name + " I want to tell you now " + Math.random());
}

var myUser=new User('jon', 'johnson');
myUser.sayName();
myUser.whoWhat();
setInterval(myUser.whoWhat, 3000);
```

And here is the console output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `setInterval()` callback loses its association with the object you've constructed. The association of a function with an object as a property value *only* affects `this` when the property value is used to make a function call. Here, you're just referencing the value (that is, acquiring a reference to the function). When the system invokes the function, `this` will be `undefined` (or the `window` object, depending on the "strict" modality).

You can ensure that `this` is the right value by using a wrapper function:

```
  setInterval(function() { myUser.whoWhat(); }, 3000);
```

In newer browsers, you can use a method from the Function prototype called `bind()`:

```
  setInterval(myUser.whoWhat.bind(myUser), 3000);
```

That has (for your purposes) the same effect, though `bind()` can do other things too.

The key thing to remember is that in JavaScript, there are no long-term relationships between functions and objects. References to functions are just plain values, and nothing special happens just because a function happens to be defined as a property of a prototype object or an object literal. The only thing that matters is how a function is actually invoked.

Comment: thx for answer Pointy! your code definitely works but I don't fully get it. I'll probably reread like 10 times. thx again.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is called the "this" problem in the MDN documentation:

> Code executed by setInterval() is run in a separate execution context
>   to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this
>   keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global)
>   object, it will not be the same as the this value for the function
>   that called setTimeout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2):

When you access a property that is a function, there is a difference if you call it directly, or if you keep the reference and call it later.

When you call it directly, the object is used as the context, but if you keep the reference for later it is not associated with the object any more, and when you call it, it will be called with the global object (window) as context.

The solution is to make the method call in a function to use in the setTimeout call:

```
setInterval(function(){ myUser.whoWhat(); }, 3000);
```